# Node how to create a callback so custom function runs synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add a callback function to a custom function so that I can use the value established in the function. However, at the moment nothing in my callback function is getting called - so the log message 'Adding the protobuf message' never gets called and the value never gets used. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. Essentially I just want to set it up to run synchronously since I need the value from the function to add as an output.

```
var protoMessage;

createProtobufMessage(function(){

    logClient.trackTrace('The protomessage is' + protoMessage);


});



function createProtobufMessage() {

}
```

Comment: You need to call the callback.

Comment: Hi SLacks, how would I call callback - do I need to give the unamed function a name and just call it at the end of the protobuf.load() call

Comment: No; just make it a parameter.

Comment: so like:
function createProtobufMessage(callback) {
....
     callback();
});

Comment: Yes; exactly...

Comment: Your title says synchronously, just be aware it may be called async depending on how you call it. Response from an Ajax request for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a parameter in `createProtobufMessage` to receive the callback.

You can then call this parameter just like any other function.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
    var protoMessage;

createProtobufMessage(function(){

    logClient.trackTrace('Adding the protobuf message');

    logClient.trackTrace('The protomessage is' + protoMessage);

    context.bindings.output = protoMessage;
    context.done();    
});


/**
* Create a protobuf message.
*/
function createProtobufMessage(callback) {

    protobuf.load(GetEnvironmentVariable('ProtoBufFilePath'), function(error, root) {

        if (error) {
            logClient.trackException('An error occured when loading the protobuf file');
            throw error;
        }

        logClient.trackTrace('Creating a new protobuf message');

        // Obtain a message type
        var messageType = root.lookup(GetEnvironmentVariable('ProtoBufMessageType'));

        // Create a new message
        var message = messageType.create({
            header: {
                protocolVersion: 1,
                messageCreationTime: 2505,
                eventId: 2505,
                clientTimestamp: 1709,
            }
        });

        // Encode a message (note that reflection encodes to a writer and we need to call finish)
        var buffer = messageType.encode(message).finish();
        var messageDec = messageType.decode(buffer);

        protoMessage = JSON.stringify(messageDec);
        logClient.trackTrace('A protobuf message has been successfully created' + protoMessage);
    });
    callback();
}
```